# Is usage of "Than that of" vs "Than those of" case agnostic?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

I've seen many cases of "than that of" and "than those of" switched with one another. Are they both really same and can be interchanged? Or do we follow some specific rules on where to use one of the either?

PS: Some seem to be of the opinion that "than that of" must be used when not referring to humans. Is it correct? Any examples otherwise?

Comment: _That_ is singular; _those_ is plural. I don’t understand quite what it is you’re asking apart from that. _Than that/those of_ is not a unit, but a preposition (_than_) governing a noun phrase consisting of a demonstrative pronoun (singular _that_, plural _those_) and a preposition (_of_) with its object. As a [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form), what determines whether the demonstrative pronoun _that/those_ should be singular or plural is the number of its logical referent.